# Laravel create customs packages with commands

Tags: php, laravel-5, command, laravel-artisan

I am looking to make a generic appointment system in Laravel and I want to use that in my other projects.
Is there any way to achieve by creating custom commands? For example, `php artisan make:auth` creates a complete login, register, forgot and reset password functionality.
I want to do the same, like `php artisan appoitment : make` and it should create the models, controllers and database migrations in that Laravel installation

Comment: Did you try anything and get any error by trying something [like this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#writing-commands) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. php artisan make:command {command name}. You can see {command name} file in app/console/commands directory.
2. change $signature to appoitment:make.
3. add your command class to app/console/Kernel.php commands list.

for example:

```
php artisan make:command AppoitmentCommand

In Kernel.php : $commands = [
    AppoitmentCommand::class
];

php artisan //you can see all commands
```

Comment: In your custom command you can run other command such as php artisan make:model or etc. For more detail read [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands)